# Word templates and custom fonts

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts

I have recently undertaken a design branding job where I was asked to create Microsoft Word templates for invoices and reports.

I have created the document with custom fonts, those which are used throughout his company branding. I realize that fonts can not be embedded so I got the client to purchase and install the fonts on his computer. The problem is that even though the fonts are now on his system Word still displays default system fonts instead of the ones I had designed the document with.

I am using Office 2011 for Mac and my client uses Office 2013 for Windows.

Comment: And what happens when they send out those invoices to their customers?  Are you expecting all of their customers to purchase these fonts as well, just so they can read their invoices correctly?  Rather than tell you a way around the issue you mention, I'd suggest that you reserve the custom fonts for those areas that you provide as images, so that the appearance will be predictable.

Comment: You've just raised an interesting question. I assumed once edited and saved as a pdf there would be no problem, the fonts would be embedded in the pdf, as it does with any Adobe program. Does word function differently?

Comment: Acrobat will not generally allow you to embed copyright-protected fonts;  it will make a substitution.  You could, though, generate the PDF as an image ... but I'm a bit confused as to how they are going to add the right data to the PDF file, unless you have made it a fillable form.  As for Word, I suspect that the fonts he's using and yours might not be the same format, i.e. are yours postscript perhaps?

Comment: Problem solved, I ended up running windows on my mac and creating the templates in office 2013, all fonts worked on his end perfectly fine.

To answer your question Debra, the idea is that my client has now a word template which he can edit when he needs to bill his own clients. The invoices themselves once filled out shouldn't be editable, he just sends them to his client as flat pdfs so that they can see what they are being billed.